# Sonarqube scanner for Msbuild v3.0.1 causes issue with Build Solution in VSTS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Recently I tried to update my SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild to v3 from v2 on my VSTS builds.

1) I re-ran my VSTS Build to make sure it was still successful before making any changes and it ran without error.

2) I updated the version of the scanner by just changing the version drop down in the task in VSTS [linked a image below of what I saw].

[image: Drop down for changing the version]

3) Then I ran the build again and on my Build Solution step I got a error.

This error had to do with trying to delete a file from the `.sonarqube/out` directory.

> Error MSB3061 : Unable to delete file "[filepath].sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_[GUID]\ProjectInfo.xml". Access to the path '[filepath].sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_[GUID]\ProjectInfo.xml" is denied

It is possible the issue is with the double slash in the file path (\) but this was not happening before I updated the version of the scanner. Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to remove to remove the files on the buildagent and re-run your test?

Comment: I looked on the Build Agent and the file did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has since been resolved with a newer version of the scanner. It was a issue with that particular version of the scanner.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would list the version of the scanner that fixed the problem.

Comment: Through VSTS and TFS you do not pick a exact version(you see 3.* but the log shows the version you are using), but I believe it was 3.1.0. This then SonarQube has moved to 4.* and it solved other issues I have seen since then.